# Error while performing Update query- Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: ''YYYYMMDDHHMMSSZ"

Tags: mysql, datetime, date-formatting

I am trying to update a datetime which is in String format `YYYYMMDDHHMMSSZ` into `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

I was trying to run a query: `Update consolidated_table SET createtimestamp_E=DATE_FORMAT(createtimestamp_E, '%Y-%m-%d %T')` but getting:

> Error Code: 1292`. Incorrect datetime value: ''

I tried inserting the csv file in datetime format, but that didn't work.

So I had to upload it in String format and now I'm trying to convert the string into date format, but in vein.

Comment: what is the output you are getting from DATE_FORMAT(createtimestamp_E, '%Y-%m-%d %T')

Comment: I tried it myself and it seems to work on my end.
Maybe you can give an example of some input so i will be able to help you any further?

Comment: Hi,I am getting an error: Error Code: 1292`. Incorrect datetime value: ''

Comment: I tried to change the script: UPDATE consolidated_table 
SET createtimestamp_E = (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(createtimestamp_E,"'",''), '%Y-%m-%d-%T')); This time i got another error: Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '20020716121838Z' for function str_to_date

Comment: Unresolved issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this issue fixed by using below command:
SUBSTRING(@var, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(@var)-1).

I further wanted to convert this column  from string to datetime for which i used the below command:

SET createtimestamp=CONVERT (SUBSTRING(@var, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(@var)-1),DATETIME)